# Почему тут не ставится запятая?

Tags: запятые, спп, егэ

> Хотя Леонтьеву очень хотелось поехать в лесничество к Петру
> Максимовичу, он решил до осени, пока(,) хотя бы вчерне не окончит
> книгу, никуда не выезжать из Ленинграда.

Comment: А почему вы предполагаете, что ее здесь нужно поставить?

Comment: В сборнике Цыбулько так написано

Answer (score 2):

Правильное предложение К. Паустовского, вообще-то, выглядит так (["Гонкое дерево"](http://paustovskiy-lit.ru/paustovskiy/text/povest-o-lesah/lesa_20.htm)):

> Хотя Леонтьеву и очень хотелось поехать в лесничество, к Петру Максимовичу, но он решил до осени, пока хотя бы вчерне не окончит книгу, никуда не уезжать из Ленинграда.

В заданиях ЕГЭ предложение имеет такой вид:
*Хотя (1) Леонтьеву очень хотелось поехать в лесничество к Петру Максимовичу (2) он решил до осени (3) пока (4) хотя бы вчерне не окончит книгу (5) никуда не выезжать из Ленинграда.*

Запятая после "пока", конечно же, не нужна (и нигде в тестах И. П. Цыбулько ее нет).
Вот [**здесь**](https://100ballnik.com/15-05-2022-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%8D-2022-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8F/) дается просто ответ: **235**.

А вот [**здесь**](https://dzen.ru/media/id/5d96ff9f0ce57b00ad55460a/variant-2-zadanie-19-ege-russkii-iazyk-36-variantov-618fd5c5d2366b1f7efaad5a) даже присутствуют пояснения:

> Запятая (2) отделяет придаточное предложение уступки (хотя...) от главного предложения [он решил не выезжать].
> Запятые (3)(5) отделяют придаточное предложение времени (пока...), которое находится внутри главного предложения [он решил не выезжать].
> (1)(4) — запятых нет.
> Обратите внимание: *хотя бы* — это усилительная частица в словосочетании *хотя бы вчерне.*
> Ответ: 235

Думаю, что Вы просто невнимательно посмотрели.